# $scope not updating after AJAX request and view change

Tags: angularjs

I have been unable to isolate my problem. Here is a jsfiddle of what I am trying to achieve and it works http://jsfiddle.net/NEuJ6/56/ . When a button is pressed, the view changes and the scope is updated.

However when I try to do it on my project with the following code, the $scope change isn't applied even with $scope.$apply(); . The view changes and $scope.foods updates properly. However the list page which is now meant to display a list of the items returned doesn't update. However if add the button to the list page and press it, the page updates fine with the new $scope.foods items. This means the issue has to do with changing views and updating the scope. However in my simple fiddle, I can change view and update scope without issues.

```
$scope.getFoods = function(){
        $scope.foods = '';
        $location.path('/list');
        $http({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/getfoods/',
            method: "POST",
            data: {address: $scope.location.address, cuisine: $scope.filters.cuisine},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).success(function (data) {
                $scope.foods = data;
                console.log($scope.foods);
                $scope.$apply();
        }).error(function (data, status) {
                console.log(status);
            }); 
    };
```

Help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It all depends on where or what scope `foods` defined.

Comment: Instead of $scope.foods=data. Push each element into the `$scope.foods, like angular.forEach(data,function(item) {$scope.foods.push(item);});`

Comment: $scope.foods is updated with data that consist of food item objects containing info such as name, price etc. that are serialized via django rest framework. I will try the out the individual pushing of data soon. Fingers crossed it works.

Comment: You don't need $scope.$apply.  The problem is likely that the view you're expecting to change is not sharing the same `$scope`, and thus doesn't see `$scope.foods`.  If you post your entire controller and the html with the two views, it would be easier to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with one of my projects. Here's what worked for me.

try this:

```
        $http({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/getfoods/',
        method: "POST",
        data: {address: $scope.location.address, cuisine:        $scope.filters.cuisine
            },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).success(function (data) {

            $scope.$apply(function(){ // put $scope var that needs to be updated
            $scope.foods = data;      // inside a function inside $apply like this
            console.log($scope.foods);
       });
          }).error(function (data, status) {
            console.log(status);
        });
```